# Android app running on Emulator but not on device_getting stackoverflow error

Tags: android, android-emulator, stack

When I am trying to open a tabactivity it is  running fine on emulator but not on real device.
the min and max sdk in manifet file as shown

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"

    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
```

### And my device is samsung tablet having 4.1.1 version

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602): java.lang.StackOverflowError

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.content.res.Resources.obtainAttributes(Resources.java:1393)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:117)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1948)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)

08-13 17:53:42.034: E/AndroidRuntime(22602):    at android.content.res.Resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) was deprecated in API 13, so it is not guaranteed to work correctly on Android 3.2 or later.  Consider using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) instead.

Stack overflow errors typically happen when a recursive function doesn't have a proper base case.  In other words, the recursive function will keep calling itself, thus adding it's variables onto the stack until the stack space is gone.  If you are using any recursive functions, be sure you have a proper base case.  If you aren't using any recursive functions, something probably went wrong in the deprecated TabActivity class.

Comment: There is no recursive function in my activity.It is happening bcoz of the deprecated tab activity.